# calculate_default_transform larger set than QGIS

Tags: qgis, rasterio

I am projection a raster from EPSG:31467 (Gauss- Krüger 3) to EPSG:32832. I have done it once in QGIS and once with rasterio.

for the correct affine transformation in rasterio I use:

```py
from rasterio.warp import calculate_default_transform

transform, width, height = calculate_default_transform(
            'EPSG:31467', 25832, 654, 866, *src.bounds)
```

The problem I have with the result is the *set-off*. Depending on the position in the raster the pixel positions shown in QGIS are off by about 100 meter in both directions. *The Manhattam distance in in average 300 m.* Compared to a resolution of 1000 m. Which I find hardly acceptable.
Than I did a *reprojection in QGIS* itself an got an off set off less than 10 m in each direction with an *average Manhattan distance of 5 m* (for some test pixels).  The resolution in QGIS is -0.004 % and in rasterio -0.0028 %.

How can I decrease the off-set between the pixel postions?

Comment: Why don't you just warp https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli.html?#warp?